# In Jackson, how do I serialize a non-Map Iterable as an array?

Tags: java, json, jackson

Basically, what is the easiest way to make this test pass without changing the asymptotic runtime (i.e., please don't tell me to copy `set1` and `set2` into a list because the whole point of `Iterables.concat()` is to avoid the copy):

```
@Test
public void jacksonObjectMapperSerializesIterableAsList() throws IOException {
  SortedSet<String> set1 = new TreeSet<>();
  set1.add("a");
  set1.add("b");
  set1.add("c");
  SortedSet<String> set2 = new TreeSet<>();
  set2.add("d");
  set2.add("e");
  set2.add("f");

  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

  // This part passes.
  StringWriter set1Writer = new StringWriter();
  mapper.writeValue(set1Writer, set1);
  assertEquals("[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\"]", set1Writer.toString());

  // This part fails.
  // The actual value is: {"empty":false}
  StringWriter setsWriter = new StringWriter();
  mapper.writeValue(setsWriter, com.google.common.collect.Iterables.concat(set1, set2));
  assertEquals("[\"a\",\"b\",\"c\",\"d\",\"e\",\"f\"]", setsWriter.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution is to configure the `ObjectMapper` with the `GuavaModule`:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().registerModule(new GuavaModule());
```

I think this was the relevant issue/fix: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-guava/issues/46